# Collate all data from each .txt file into one results file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have ~2000 .txt files that each contain three columns similar to this example, where columns 1-2 are the same in each file:

```
A   Func1   6
B   Func1   5
C   Func1   17
D   Func1   47
E   Func1   37
F   Func1   42
G   Func1   22
H   Func1   13
I   Func1   81
```

I want to collate all data from each .txt file into one results file. I just need the data from column 3 oriented into rows for each file. I also need the file name in the first column:

```
file_name   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
file1.txt   6  5  17 47 37 42 22 13 81
file2.txt   8  12 22 84 1  43 54 90 10
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a shell loop with awk and `paste`:

```bsh
for f in *.txt
do
    printf "%s\t" "$f"   # print filename
    awk '{print $3}' "$f" | paste -s  # take third column and transpose
done
```

With output like so:

```
file1.txt   6   5   17  47  37  42  22  13  81
file2.txt   12  11  77  107 97  102 82  73  141
```

The header line can be generated from any file:

```bsh
printf "%s\t" "file_name"
awk '{print $1}' file1.txt | paste -s
```

Comment: Thanks @muru ! I just realised that the 2nd column has (a variable number of) spaces in it so I actually want to take the last column instead of the 3rd column from each file... how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @user2861089 in the awk command, use `$NF` instead of `$3`.